# React Native Multi-Transtation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, native, translate

In my project I need to let the user select a desired language and thus change all the text in the project to the language he requested.

I would love to know if there is a library in React Native recommended that does the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of similar libraries, called i18n~ etc, i can suggest [react-i18next](https://react.i18next.com/getting-started) it's very simple in configuration and usage, especially with useTranslation [hook](https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook) and they have a good react-native example [here](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/react-native). You obviously need to add translation files to you project with language translations that you will support. You can use this with some libraries that allow you to save data to persistent-store, as [AsyncStorage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage) or [EncryptedStorage](https://github.com/emeraldsanto/react-native-encrypted-storage) in order to save user language preferences globally to the whole app.